# Can't refresh download link to continue downloading my file from google drive using IDM

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-drive, download-manager

I started downloading a *2.2 GB* file from google drive using IDM (Internet Download Manager). Now I have downloaded 70% and IDM is saying to refresh the download link. I am unable to refresh the download link because IDM doesn't catch the download link when I start downloading *(the downloading starts in Google Chrome)*. If I start the downloading manually using IDM, it starts downloading but from 0% *(the old file remains there)*. If I update the link using properties, it still raises the same error.

How do I refresh my google drive download link in IDM?

Comment: I don't personal use weird, sketchy looking download managers, but you may look around for some way to import a link. Maybe if you copy the download link and import it, it will resume properly. Just a guess.

Comment: @LayneBernardo The link redirects to the login link when downloading with idm.

Comment: When you look at the download details, what does it say next to "Resume capability"? Also, how did you get it to download in IDM originally?

Comment: I have the IDM extension. If I right click on the download link in chrome, there is an option to transfer the download to IDM. It works successfully but does not resume the old download. It makes a new one. Also , the file has Resume capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to solve and I am posting this here for any one struggling with this, Just refresh the download from another browser like Internet explorer

Step by step

```
 1. tell IDM to refresh download(waiting for download screen will appear)

2. copy download address

 3. open another browser other than chrome

    4. copy download link into address bar and go
```

The download will refresh

Comment: This is a great workaround for sure, but calling it a "solve" is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh the download link of google drive .. then sorry to say It can't be done in case of the google drive link. Otherwise "copy the download address" method will be work in other links expect google drive link.

Answer (score 0):

just go and copy the new link address and then go to IDM right click on the file
and chose properties and then in the page open up u can see "Address" just ctrl+A the old link and delete it and paste the new link then hit ok button then "Resume download" you are good to go （￣︶￣）↗